# Does SQL Server Have An Equivalent of MySql Workbench?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I have SQL Server 2012 developer edition installed. I'm looking for an equivalent to MySql's Workbench where I can view databases, configurations, test sql queries, etc.  I dont see anything in the Configuration Tools folder in the Start Menu that falls into this category though.

Comment: You need to install SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called Sql Server Management Studio: Install the 'Management Tools - Complete'

Installation -> Add New Features to Existing installation

[image]

Comment: If you have the RTM CD or an ISO of RTM, probably easier to just [download the version with SP1 already included](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) (choose SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe or SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe depending on platform).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a step-by-step guide to install SQL Server Management Studio.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx